# How to remove this while scrolling in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[My VSCode when i scrolled down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRCaz.png)

[How it normally is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuGf3.png)

I just noticed it now and when i scroll there is like a preview of the previous lines of code. I don't know if its a feature that i enabled or a bug. Anyone knows how to remove it? Thanks!

I tried opening and closing the files but it still comes up. I would like to remove it as it bothers me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you have enabled **sticky scroll** in VS code settings.

File > Preferences > Settings - Search for 'sticky scroll'

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I have been searching but couldn't find the right words to describe it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I feel lucky to find it so quickly.